# How do i count number of values in datagridview based on the select Statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I had this problem on how to count using sqlserver query the number of specific values based on the inputs in a datagridview column.

For example:

This is the data,

```
  Orange = Fruit
  Apple = Fruit
  Mango = Fruit
  Carrot = Vegetable
  Beans = Vegetable
```

Now, the case is;

If the rows of my datagridview column 1 contains "Orange","Apple",

I want the result to be like;

```
   Fruit  2
```

And So on.

The sql query should count the number of fruits that the datagridview column provided.

I'm so confused on how do i do this with sql query and vb.net. 
PLEASE HELP!

Comment: I would suggest reading up on `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY` in SQL Server, as this will easily achieve what you are looking to do - [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/36f02/1). However, you haven't shown what you have tried so far or clearly mentioned what you are trying to achieve by what means. Please read SO's help on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: Maybe i'll find some other way to do it. thanks man..